# How do I make sure code isn't called multiple times, but not block it for the whole program execution as with dispatch_once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

Say there's something I want to make sure never gets called while it's being executed already.

Take for example a `UIScrollView` where the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method is called every single time any zooming occurs. What if I wanted to use `[UIView animateWithDuration...]` the very first time it's called, but not allow the subsequent calls to "overwrite" the already playing animation?

`dispatch_once` would work perfectly, if it weren't for the fact that it only allows it to run once per program execution, when I need it to run multiple times, just not at the same time overwriting one another.

How would I go about blocking subsequent calls from messing things up?

Comment: How about using a flag to check whether the function/ block is already running?

Comment: Basically the same problem: [Looping `dispatch_after()` in a method causes many simultaneous dispatches when method is rerun](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21664412)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand then something like this should work (since the delegate is always called from the main thread):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    static BOOL busy = NO;

    if (!busy) {
        busy = YES;

       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
           // your animations
       } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
           busy = NO;
       }];
    }
}
```

This code ensures the animation can only happen one at a time.

Comment: This would block `scrollViewDidScroll:` in every instance if the animation is running in any other instance. If that's not intended, you can use a property instead.

Comment: Yes, good point. This code does assume only a single instance of this view controller exists in the app at any one time. Using an ivar instead of the static would be a good idea.